# why do i get syntax eror?

Tags: syntax, verilog

i want to make the leds on my zed board to blink from one side to the other and this is my code :

```
module blinky(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,
    input wire direction,
    output reg [7:0] leds
    );

always @(posedge clk) begin 


                    if (reset==1) begin
                    // reset the leds to the default state
                        leds <=1;

                    end
                    else begin 
                          // move the light from right to left 
                          if (direction == 1)
                          // standard way to do a rotation in Verilog 
                              leds<= {leds[6:0],leds[7]};
                          end 

            // move the light from left to right 
            else begin 
            leds <= {leds[0],leds[6:1]};
           end
         end

    end


endmodule
```

how ever when i write this statment :

> else begin 
>               leds <= {leds[0],leds[6:1]};  end

i get syntax eror . I cant understand why . could anyone help me get the syntax right ? i searched google and found couple of methods but all give me the same eror.

Comment: There could be many reason which we can't tell about because you have not show the COMPLETE! code. e.g. your `else` could be wrongly placed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot a `begin` after `if (direction == 1)`:

One of the reason it is difficult to spot is that you indenting is rather erratic.

---

Coding outline is very personal.
I prefer my `begin` in line with my `end` as my editor gives
a nice matching line.
I also use 3 spaces as indent because with deep indenting I can't keep track
of where everything is. But as I said that is personal:

[image]